# How to find the data dependencies of a MachineInstr in an LLVM MachineBasicBlock?

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization

Preface: I want to point out that a form of this [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376958/how-to-figure-out-if-particular-llvm-instruction-depends-on-the-other), but without many details and with no answers.  I am hoping that a more detailed question will be more answerable.

What I'm trying to do is figure out if I can switch the order of two llvm::MachineInstr objects in the same llvm::MachineBasicBlock.  I don't want to modify the instructions, and I don't care about moving instructions outside of a MachineBasicBlock.  If it's important, I'm working with the [avr-llvm backend](https://github.com/avr-llvm/llvm) which is a branch of LLVM 3.7.  The backend is fairly pre-release at this time but I'm using it for research, so this isn't really a concern.

My intention is to use this code in a `MachineFunctionPass` inserted in `addILPOpts`, so the registers are still in SSA form.  I'll have something that looks essentially like this:

```
bool runOnMachineFunction(MachineFunction &MF) override {

  for (MachineFunction::iterator b = MF.begin(), be = MF.end(); b != be; ++b) {
    MachineInstr *prev = NULL;

    for (MachineBasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin(), ie = b->end(); i != ie; ++i) {
      bool canSwap = false;

      if (prev != NULL) {
        canSwap = dependency(*prev, *i);
      }
      prev = i;

      if (canSwap) errs() << "yup";
    }
  }

  return false;
}

bool dependency(MachineInstr &MI0, MachineInstr &MI1) {
  // somehow determine if MI1 depends on MI0 being executed first
  return false;
}
```

I have tried messing around with `MachineRegisterInfo`, but if I get this from the `MachineFunction` like this:

```
MachineRegisterInfo &MRI = MF.getRegInfo();
```

When I call `MRI.getVRegDef`, everything seems to just return NULL.  Am I trying to use this too early, or too late perhaps?

The concept of use-def and def-use chains discussed in the [Programmer's Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-def-use-use-def-chains) seems to only apply to IR instructions.  Is there a similar data structure for machine instructions?

Comment: getVregDef is only meaningful before register allocation. But even at this point, this won't be helpful. You need to model load/store and so on if you want an answer in general.

Comment: @Joky instructions at this point are still in SSA form, so it's before physical register allocation.  Is there a stage at which more generic data dependency information is available?

Comment: Try RDFGraph in lib/Target/Hexagon